# setState is not being called onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Working with material-ui v3.9.4, react-router v3. Created a left nav bar with a List containing Link items to redirect to another page. For some reason when I click on an item, the page is redirected, but the state is not updated until the second click to show the active item. Any idea as to why that is? Code below. I've console logged the setState change, which doesnt print until the second click.

```
class LeftNavigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedIndex: 0,
            sidebarCollapsed: false,
        }
    }

    handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
        console.log("CLICKED");                                             //prints first click
        this.setState({ selectedIndex: index }, () => {
            console.log("SELECTED INDEX:: ", this.state.selectedIndex)      //prints second click
        });
    }

    handleCollapse = () => {
        this.setState({ sidebarCollapsed: !this.state.sidebarCollapsed })
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={this.state.sidebarCollapsed ? classes.rootCollapsed : classes.root}>
                <List component="nav">
                    <ListItem
                        button
                        component={props => <Link to="./pageOne" {...props} />}
                        selected={this.state.selectedIndex === 0}
                        onClick={(event) => this.handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
                    >
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <CalendarIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.listText }} primary="Page One" />
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem
                        button
                        onClick={(event) => this.handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
                        component={props => <Link to="./pageTwo" {...props} />}
                        selected={this.state.selectedIndex === 1}
                    >
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <MailIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.listText }} primary="Page Two" />
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem
                        button
                        component={props => <Link to="./pageThree" {...props} />}
                        selected={this.state.selectedIndex === 2}
                        onClick={(event) => this.handleListItemClick(event, 2)}
                    >
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <NotesIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.listText }} primary="Page Three" />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>

                <div
                    onClick={this.handleCollapse}>
                    {this.state.sidebarCollapsed ? <ChevronRight /> :
                        <div><ChevronLeft /><p>Collapse sidebar</p></div>}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(LeftNavigation );
```

Comment: Is there any chance that this sidebar is being rendered again from scratch on route change like the following flow: `load page 1 > render sidebar > click link > load page 2 > render sidebar again > click link > set page 2 to active` ?

Comment: @TomFinney after doing some CDM logs, that was exactly what was happening. set the index in CDM after getting the url location and it works as expected now. that was driving me insane. THANK YOU!